# NBA - Why can recently signed players not be traded but sign-and-trades are allowed?

Tags: basketball, nba, cba

What are the contractual differences in signing a player vs executing a sign-and-trade that prevent a recently signed player from being traded but allow for a s&t?

Comment: Potentially, your answer is buried here (and following questions): http://www.cbafaq.com/salarycap.htm#Q84